# JAXBContext.newInstance() is not loading class for each invocation

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, weblogic

I have read everywhere that `JAXBContext.newInstance(SampleClass.class)` will load the `SampleClass` and create a `JAXBContext` object from it. For example, last answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584821/jaxbcontext-newinstance-memory-leak) and there were blogs as well.

But when I do following then I do not see class getting loaded 10000 times. I verified this using a profiling tool that `SampleClass` is not loading 10000 times.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestData.class);
        jaxbContext.hashCode();
        jaxbContext.toString();
        jaxbContext.getClass();
    }
```

Is my understanding about `JAXBContext.newInstance` wrong?

I know that if a class is loaded by JVM then it will not be loaded again but this is what I have read everywhere that using `JAXBContext.newInstance()` will load the class each time.

---

**EDIT:** Here is more observation from jVisualVM, I invoked it ~10000 but only ~200-300 class loading happened, and then 174 classes were shown as unloaded.

Comment: The JVM loads a class once (as far as I am aware), hence the static{} block often used to do actions on first load of a class. Doesn't newInstance inherently mean a new *object*?

Comment: @SameerPuri Yes, you are right that JVM loads class only once, but this more question about how `JAXBContext` works in terms of class loading because it possible to load class many times even if it is already loaded. `JAXBContext.newInstance()` is a like a factory method to get the new instance of the passed class but before the instance is created, whether class will be loaded again or not is the question.