# Solving Memory Leak with JAXBContext in Java Application

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, jaxb, yourkit

I'm trying to diagnose and resolve what I believe is a serious memory leak with `JAXBContext`. However, despite many attempts to do so, I'm unsuccessful.

In short, my application uses a small and consistent amount of memory during the first 50 min of execution. After around 50 min, the number of classes/memory increases from less than 4,000 (classes) to around 8,000 (similar increase occurs with memory). It remains this way until about 1 hr and 16 min when the number of classes (as observed in `YourKit`) grows to about 246,000 during the next 15-20 min of execution.

Just about the same time memory/class usage increases my program starts uploading images to eBay server using EBay's Java SDK [`com.ebay.sdk.pictureservice.eps`].

I analyzed the `Object Allocation Call Tree` in `YourKit` and it seems my program calls the following methods:

```
public int uploadPictures(PhotoDisplayCodeType arg0, PictureInfo[] arg1) {
    int arg2 = 0;

    for (int arg3 = 0; arg3 < arg1.length; ++arg3) {
            if (this.uploadPicture(arg0, arg1[arg3])) {
                ++arg2;
        }
    }

 return arg2;
}


public boolean uploadPicture(PhotoDisplayCodeType arg0, PictureInfo arg1) {
    UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType arg2 = new UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType();
    if (arg0.equals(PhotoDisplayCodeType.SUPER_SIZE) || arg0.equals(PhotoDisplayCodeType.PICTURE_PACK)) {
                arg2.setPictureSet(PictureSetCodeType.SUPERSIZE);
   }

    return this.UpLoadSiteHostedPicture(arg1, arg2);
}


public boolean UpLoadSiteHostedPicture(PictureInfo arg0, UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType arg1) {
        ApiLogging arg2 = this.apiContext.getApiLogging();

        System.out.println("Starting picture upload..");

        try {
            Document arg3 = this.marshal(arg1);
            this.addAuthToken(arg3);
            String arg4;
            if (arg2 != null && arg2.isLogSOAPMessages()) {
                arg4 = XmlUtil.getXmlStringFromDom(arg3);
                this.logMessage("UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest", arg4);
            }


            arg4 = this.xmlToString(arg3);
            String arg5 = this.sendFile(arg0.getPictureFilePath(), arg4);
            if (arg2 != null && arg2.isLogSOAPMessages()) {
                Document arg6 = XmlUtil.createDom(arg5);
                String arg7 = XmlUtil.getXmlStringFromDom(arg6);
                this.logMessage("UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponse", arg7);
            }

            UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponseType arg9 = this.unmarshal(arg5);
            arg0.setReponse(arg9);
            if (arg9.getErrors() != null && arg9.getErrors().length != 0) {
                if (arg9.getErrors().length > 0 && arg9.getAck() == AckCodeType.WARNING) {
                    arg0.setURL(arg9.getSiteHostedPictureDetails().getFullURL());
                    arg0.setErrorType("PICTURE SERVICE RESPONSE WARNING");
                    arg0.setErrorMessage(arg9.getErrors()[0].getShortMessage());
                    if (arg2 != null && arg2.isLogExceptions()) {
                        log.warn("PICTURE SERVICE RESPONSE WARNING");
                        log.warn(arg9.getErrors()[0].getShortMessage());
                    }

                    return true;
                } else {
                    arg0.setErrorType("PICTURE SERVICE RESPONSE ERROR");
                    arg0.setErrorMessage(arg9.getErrors()[0].getShortMessage());
                    if (arg2 != null && arg2.isLogExceptions()) {
                        log.error("PICTURE SERVICE RESPONSE ERROR");
                        log.error(arg9.getErrors()[0].getShortMessage());
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                arg0.setURL(arg9.getSiteHostedPictureDetails().getFullURL());
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception arg8) {
            arg0.setErrorType("PICTURE SERVICE UPLOAD ERROR");
            arg0.setErrorMessage(arg8.getMessage());
            if (arg2 != null && arg2.isLogExceptions()) {
                log.error("fail to upload picture to eBay picture server!");
                log.error(arg8.getMessage());
            }

            return false;
        }
}



private Document marshal(UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType arg0)
            throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException {

        **// Is this line causing memory leak?**
        JAXBContext arg1 = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType.class }); 
        Marshaller arg2 = arg1.createMarshaller();
        if (arg0 == null) {
            arg0 = new UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType();
        }

        JAXBElement arg3 = (new ObjectFactory()).createUploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest(arg0);
        DocumentBuilderFactory arg4 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        arg4.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder arg5 = arg4.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document arg6 = arg5.newDocument();
        arg2.marshal(arg3, arg6);
        return arg6;
    }
```

My program calls `uploadPictures()` a few hundred times in a row. It seems to me that memory starts increasing dramatically right at about the time program calls this function.

Is my diagnoses correct? How can I fix it?

**Update:**

I found this [related thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584821/jaxbcontext-newinstance-memory-leak). If my diagnoses is correct it seems to be a bug with version the of `JAXBContext` used by `EBay SDK`.

**Update:**

I tried resolving this problem by changing `JAXBContext` class to a singleton but unfortunately it did not solve the issue:

```
public class JAXBContextFactory {
    private static JAXBContextFactory instance = new JAXBContextFactory();

    private static final Map< String, JAXBContext > INSTANCES = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, JAXBContext>();



    private JAXBContextFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns an existing JAXBContext if one for the particular namespace exists, 
     * else it creates an instance adds it to a internal map.
     * @param contextPath the context path
     * @throws JAXBException exception in creating context
     * @return a created JAXBContext
     */
    public JAXBContext getJaxBContext(final String contextPath) throws JAXBException {


     JAXBContext context = INSTANCES.get(contextPath);
        if (context == null) {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath);
            INSTANCES.put(contextPath, context);
        }
        return context;
    }


    /**
     * Returns an existing JAXBContext if one for the particular namespace exists,
     * else it creates an instance adds it to a internal map.
     * @param contextPath the context path
     * @throws JAXBException exception in creating context
     * @return a created JAXBContext
     */
    public JAXBContext getJaxBContext(final Class contextPath) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = INSTANCES.get(contextPath.getName());
        if (context == null) {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath);
            INSTANCES.put(contextPath.getName(), context);
        }
        return context;
    }

    /**
     * Get instance.
     * @return Instance of this factory
     */
    public static JAXBContextFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

When I look at `Inspections` in `YourKit` under `"Other memory oddities"` the only problem I detect is 243,959 `"Classes with same name"`. When I inspect classes I see they all contain the term `'JAXB'` in them. Based on these observations I have a few questions:

**1)** Why isn't `Singleton` pattern solving problem of creating many `JAXBContext`?

**2)** Even without `Singleton`, why aren't all relevant classes being garbage collected once my application clearly finishes using them / uploading images? I don't reference the `JAXBContext` class after upload is complete.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `marshal(UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType arg0)` method you have the line

```
// Is this line causing memory leak?
JAXBContext arg1 = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType.class });
```

Although this line is not strictly a memory-leak,
it uses much memory, and takes much CPU time,
because it creates a new heavy `JAXBContext` object every time.
After return from this method
the local variable `JAXBContext arg1` is not referenced anymore,
but it will stay in memory until it is garbage-collected
(and this might not happen for a long time).

You should replace this line by

```
JAXBContext arg1 = JAXBContextFactory.getInstance().getJaxBContext(UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequestType.class);
```

This should give you big improvement in memory usage and CPU time.

Comment: Thanks! I only replaced one instance of JAXBContext with Singleton. Now that I've replaced all instances observed leak seizes..